# Perform While loop Php

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Sorry, this is a bit noobish, I cant get a simple while statement to execute while the condition is true and false if no results:

```
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers M, professor P
WHERE P.id = M.id;";
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    do {
        echo $row;
    } 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
} else {
    die('No results.');
}
```

The problem I see with this code is `$query` is never being called in the `mysql_fetch_array()` should this be changed?

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. This would throw syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `while` statements don't have `else`s. I believe that's nearly unique to Python. Instead, you can do this:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    do {
        echo $row;
    } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
} else {
    die('No results.');
}
```

Comment: This throws error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM markers M, professor P
WHERE P.id = M.id;";
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    do {
        echo $row;
    } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
} else {
    die('No results.');
}`

Comment: This is the most complete answer, but remember to execute your query so that $result is defined.

Comment: You have to execute the query first. $result = mysql_query($query); Also, just so we are clear, echo $row will only display 'Array()'

Comment: @user975947: Have you connected to a database?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following condition:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
  die('No Result');
}
```

or simplier:

```
if ( !mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
  die('No Result');
}
```